# String.Format currencies fractional part

Tags: c#, format, currency

I've searched a lot here and on other websites but I haven't quite found the exact solution I'm looking for.

I want to output a price based on the current culture. I've performed the following tests:

```
decimal price = 909865747.98M;
decimal price2 = 90986574798M;

string frFR = string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR"), "{0:C}", price);
string frFR2 = string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR"), "{0:C}", price2);
string co = string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-CO"), "{0:C}", price);
string co2 = string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-CO"), "{0:C}", price2);
```

and I got the following results

```
frFR: 909 865 747,98 €
frFR2: 90 986 574 798,00 €
co: $909.865.747,98
co2: $90.986.574.798,00
```

I would like not to get the fractional part if the decimal number is actually an integer. But I want to keep the decimal specarator provided by the culture

Any idea ?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1):

try using ([custom numeric formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))  In your case it would be:

```
string frFR = string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
            (new CultureInfo("fr-FR")).NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern % 2 == 0 ?
                   "{0}{1:#,##0.##}" : "{1:#,##0.##}{0}", 
            new RegionInfo(new CultureInfo("fr-FR").LCID).CurrencySymbol, price);
string frFR2 = string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR"), 
            (new CultureInfo("fr-FR")).NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern % 2 == 0 ?
                   "{0}{1:#,##0.##}" : "{1:#,##0.##}{0}",
            new RegionInfo(new CultureInfo("fr-FR").LCID).CurrencySymbol, price2);

string co = string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-CO"),
            (new CultureInfo("es-CO")).NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern % 2 == 0 ? 
                   "{0}{1:#,##0.##}" : "{1:#,##0.##}{0}",
            new RegionInfo(new CultureInfo("es-CO").LCID).CurrencySymbol, price);
string co2 = string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-CO"),
            (new CultureInfo("es-CO")).NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern % 2 == 0 ? 
                   "{0}{1:#,##0.##}" : "{1:#,##0.##}{0}",
            new RegionInfo(new CultureInfo("es-CO").LCID).CurrencySymbol, price2);
```

Use `ISOCurrencySymbol` instead of `CurrencySymbol` if you want the ISO standard currency code instead of the symbol.

Here's a method to do it

```
public static string FormatCurrency(decimal amount, string culture, 
       bool useIsoCurrencySymbol = false)
{
   var ci = new CultureInfo(culture);
   return string.Format ci,
        ci.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern % 2 == 0 ? 
           "{0}{1:#,##0.##}" : "{1:#,##0.##}{0}",
        useIsoCurrencySymbol?
           new RegionInfo(ci.LCID).ISOCurrencySymbol:
           new RegionInfo(ci.LCID).CurrencySymbol, amount);
}
```

NOTE:  thousands separator for "fr-FR" is, apparently, indeed a space, not a period or a comma.

Comment: I added current culture currency symbol

Comment: Thanks. But that does not do it ;) Indeed, The currency sometimes is at the beginning of the price and sometimes at the end... According on the country. And with this formatting, don't you override the decimal separator ?

Comment: that is still not working properly because you are using the current culture and not the explicitly specified one, and you do not place the currency symbol correctly. I get "EUR909 865 747,98" for example ;)
I think the custom numeric formats are cool but nothing you want to use for currencies because of the order how the number and symbols could be placed etc... Also dot and comma have different meanings in some cultures..

Comment: If you read the section in the link I provided it says that the decimal point in the format represents the decimal separator, and will be replaced by whatever the culture decimal separator. "*The "." custom format specifier inserts a localized decimal separator into the result string*". As to the comma, it is not as clear.  I have edited to use the specified culture, instead of the current one.

Comment: I think I figured out how to get the currency symbol at the right place however I have not tested it... see if it works

Comment: And I tested thousands separator and it works correctly as well

Answer (score 1):

Check if your decimal is actually an integer or if it has digits by doing the simple check `decimalvalue % 1 == 0`

And if it is an integer, just use a format string without digits: `{0:C0}`

```
string formatPrice = price % 1 == 0 ? "{0:C0}" : "{0:C}";
string formatPrice2 = price2 % 1 == 0 ? "{0:C0}" : "{0:C}";

string frFR = string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR"), formatPrice, price);
string frFR2 = string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR"), formatPrice2, price2);
```

Comment: That could be a solution but kind of overkill to do that on every price output...

Comment: just write yourself a helper function which does it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
List<decimal> lst = new List<decimal>()
{
    909865747.98M,
    90986574798M
};

List<string> results = new List<string>();

foreach(decimal d in lst)
{
     if(d.Equals(decimal.Truncate(d)))
         results.Add(d.ToString("C0",ci));
     else
         results.Add(d.ToString("C",ci));
}
```

Or if instead a list you want a dictionary already containing your desired cultureinfo objects,after the `List<decimal>` replace with this:

```
Dictionary<CultureInfo, List<string>> results = new Dictionary<CultureInfo, List<string>>()
{
     {new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR"),new List<string>()},
     {new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-CO"),new List<string>()}
};

foreach(decimal d in lst)
{
      if (d.Equals(decimal.Truncate(d)))
      {
           foreach (var item in results)
           {
               item.Value.Add(d.ToString("C0", item.Key));
           }
      }
      else
      {
           foreach (var item in results)
           {
               item.Value.Add(d.ToString("C", item.Key));
           }
      }
}
```

If for a one liner:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
string frFR2 = price2.Equals(decimal.Truncate(price2)) ? price2.ToString("C0",ci) : price2.ToString("C",ci);
string frFR = price.Equals(decimal.Truncate(price)) ? price.ToString("C0",ci) : price.ToString("C",ci);
```